# Getting CV error AND training error in caret R

Tags: r, performance, validation, cross-validation

I divided my data set into train and test set. On the train set I use 10-fold cross validation. Which should give average CV_train error and average CV_validation error. Looking at averages of CV_train and CV_validation error would give me an indication if I'm overfitting/underfitting. But I only seem to get the average CV_validation error

```
library(caret)

train.control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10, returnResamp="all", savePredictions="final")

model <- train(money ~ ., method="rf", data=train, trControl=train.control)

model$results
```

I tried several things, but they are all results from CV_validations. Is it even possible to get  the CV_training error? If not, how can you see if your model is underfit/overfit? Because the test set will be used at the very last when the model is all done (tuned etc)

Answer (score 0):

It can help:

```
summary(model)

summary(model)$statistics$Accuracy

model

ggplot2::ggplot(model)
```